# Is there any way to create a "push" IObservable?

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

ReactiveUI has a bunch of different ways to create `IObservable`s from existing sources, such as another `IObservable`, an `IEnumerable`, an `event`, etc, but as near as I can tell it doesn't have any way to actually *originate* one, which you would think should be the simplest possible case!

It seems obvious that there should be a built-in way to create an object that implements `IObservable<T>`, with some sort of `SetNewValue(T value)` method that you can call to push a new value out to all the subscribers.  But I don't see it, either in the documentation or in Intellisense.

I know this could be worked around with `Observable.FromEvent`, but that feels like a hack.  I'm not looking for an `event`; I'm looking for an object.  Am I missing something?  Does this exist and I just don't know what to look for, or is the `FromEvent` workaround the best thing I'm gonna find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a Subject (or PublishSubject in other languages' implementation of Rx), and it does exactly what you describe!

Comment: Looking at the `Subject` class, it doesn't appear that there's any way to create one without already having either an `IObservable` and an `IObserver`, or another `ISubject`.  What I'm looking for is a starting point that doesn't depend on any preexisting observable objects.

Comment: you can create Subject and just send OnNext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229173(v=vs.103)

Comment: @kenny Ah, I was looking at the `Subject` class.  Didn't see there was also a `Subject<T>` class.  That's helpful, thanks!

Comment: Also there's Observable.Create